# How to debug .NET Core/Standard unit tests in Visual Studio 2017 Mac?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nunit, .net-standard, visual-studio-mac

I have a [project](https://github.com/matthargett/react-native-windows/tree/netstandard) that has implementation in a netstandard 1.6 project, and my unit tests are in a .NET Core 2.0 project. I'm running Visual Studio 2017 Mac version 7.3 (build 764).

The tests run from the Unit Test pad just fine (green circle and console output happens if I add output), but the debugger doesn't break when I set a breakpoint or expicitly throw an exception in the test. I've tried right-clicking on the test and selecting 'Debug Test' and right-clicking the test and selecting 'Run With'->'.NET Core Debugger'.

Here's a screenshot of the project with the project nodes expanded, the unit test displayed, the Unit Test pad expanded, and the About window up so the exact VS2017 Mac version is shown.

[image]

Is this a bug in VS2017 Mac, or am I missing something?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 7.2.2. So maybe it is a bug in 7.3 Preview.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with VS Mac 7.3 (build 764). I would look at the debugger output (Application Output window) to see if symbols are being loaded for your test assembly.  Are you building a debug version? Are there any errors in the IDE log (Help - Open Log Directory)?

Comment: After a reboot, I tried again and it prompted me to enter admin credentials. If this prompt happened before, it's possible I cancelled out of it by accident (or it was hidden behind other windows). After entering the admin credentials correctly, breakpoints were hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the debugger process needed to be granted some admin rights. After rebooting my machine and trying again to debug my unit test, I was prompted to enter the user credentials for an admin user. Once I did that, I was able to hit breakpoints just fine.

It's possible I cancelled out of the request for admin credentials by accident (or it was hidden behind other windows) when trying to debug wasn't working.

Comment: Same problem, have to launch my Visual Studio as admin cause the .NetCore app was installed with an admin account